# VideoCapture can't open file when debugging in VS 2010

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-debugging

When I run the code, the video file opens perfectly. When I am debugging it doesn't open. I have put the command line arguments in the debug properties and I have checked they are loaded properly. I also tried to put the file name in the constructor (without argv) but fails again. Any ideas?

```
VideoCapture myCapture(argv[1]);
if (!myCapture.isOpened())
{
    cout << "Can not load video file" << endl;
    return -2;
}
```

Comment: sorry, what do you meant by it opens while running the code, but doesnt open while debugging ?
I might be missing some terminology, so try to expand

Comment: ok. There is a condition in the code I posted where it checks if the video file is opened properly, !myCapture.isOpened(). When I run this the condition is false. When in debug mode it is true and the program terminates (return -2).

Comment: oh, that sounds weird, you tried, VideoCapture myCapture("finename.avi"); ?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work either. Very weird

Comment: Is your file in the project directory ?
If not, are you sure the path is right, to make sure, things are fine, just try running the videcapture using webcam, if it gives results then, there must be an issue with the file

Comment: The file is in the executable directory and I have tried different files. It compiles and runs perfectly loading the video. I just can't open a damn video in debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you specified both debug and release version of the libraries in dependency list for debug configuration. Generally this kind of problems are result of that.

There are two versions of the libraries.

opencv_X.lib  (release libraries)

opencv_Xd.lib (debug libraries)

List only debug versions of libraries for debug configuration and release versions for release configuration in Linker's Additional Dependency section.

Comment: No, that's not it. I have linked correctly against the debug mode libraries but still VideoCapture fails to open any video.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently. The video file opened in the release mode but failed to open in the debug mode.

It turns out that the VideoCapture class of OpenCV needs the opencv_ffmpeg****_**.dll to open the video regardless of whether the project is in the release or debug mode.

I fixed it by adding opencv_ffmpeg2411_64.dll to the directory that contains the debug mode executable. The .dll can be found in opencv\x64.....\bin. The release mode worked for me because the release directory containing the executable had the opencv_ffmpeg2411_64.dll.

**Note 1:** For x86 projects, opencv_ffmpeg2411.dll should be used instead of opencv_ffmpeg2411_64.dll and "x64" in the OpenCV path should be replaced with x86.

**Note 2:** Replace 2411 in the name of the .dll with OpenCV version being used for the project.